# Submit Points for Players

Tags: asp.net, database, drupal

I need to build a secure web application that allows sports coaches to go in and add points (numerical values) to each of their own sport players.

Each coach should only have access to their own information (through their email and a password) and an area that lets them update only their player's points.

There is a total of 4,000 coaches and 10,000 players that have to allocated to their appropriate coaches.

I have attached an image of how that would work through a crappy hand drawing.

What would be the best web application to develop this on?

[Web Map of Coaches and Players relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFn3p.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is highly subjective. The world is your oyster. It sounds like your webapp is essentially a nice UI layer over a database.

Personally, because I work in these a lot, I'd use Yii (PHP) as a backend and set up models to match my tables in a SQL database. I'd create a controller as an API to expose those models to AJAX calls.

In the SQL database itself, I'd set up the coach/player relationships, as well as access rights for the different coach login profiles and admin rights for the admin profiles.

Then I'd set up an AngularJS frontend to display it all. With Angular, and other frameworks, it'd be really easy to rig up a table using filters to make player info searchable and filterable on things like name, score, player number, etc. I'd also want an interface to add coaches, and you'd want to give coaches the ability to add players.

It's so subjective though. You could do a noSQL database, java backend, c++ backend, scala, nodeJS, react.js, etc, etc. There's no one "right" solution. It basically comes down to your own programming preferences.

Comment: Would this be something that you would consider building for the right price?

Answer (score 1):

Seth pretty much summed up the very broadness this question brings for answers, but I actually created something very similar to this in Drupal. This website/app was used to run a multi-day fishing tournament.

The quick and dirty answer here (when using Drupal anyway) would be to restrict access through creatively setting up Roles and Taxonomy Terms for the coaches and players and only allowing Coaches to see players that have a certain term attached to them (when I say Coaches and Players, Coaches could be Drupal 'Users' and Players could be a content type, for example). You could then create another content type (entity) to hold the Points and then attach the Points to each player.

Another solution would be using Organic Groups and making the coaches group admins and putting their players in their own groups... So many different ways to handle this.

The reason I suggested Drupal was because a lot of the grunt work is already done for you. It already has the options to create/manage Users, restrict access to content and set up entities and tie them all together. This could totally be built from the ground up, as Seth suggested or it could be built on a framework or an existing content management system.